# Shooting animation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating shooting in Unity, I've set up everything but the problem is that I want the animation to play only on single click but in my script it plays animation infinitely while holding the button. Check the script below. Thanks.

```
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public Transform firePoint;
private Animator anim;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
        anim.SetBool("isShooting", true);

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        anim.SetBool("isShooting", false);
    }

}
```

Comment: if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        anim.SetBool("isShooting", false);
    }

Comment: Lol accidentally, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: First Transition]Set 2 States with just Keys on time = 0 the end position Shooting and the end position idle. From idle to shooting with a trigger parameter. From shooting to idle just a time transition. Ps shooting can be done with multiple frames too. Hope it helps.[image: SecondTransition]

Comment: Can you explain more efficiently? I can't understand what do you mean, sorry.

Comment: I have added some pictures

Comment: What about script?

Comment: You call each time you shoot the Trigger parameter not the bool and let the state go to idle Automatically

Comment: Thanks so much, that's it.

Comment: No problem. You also may need to give your Bullet an initial speed or impulse :D

Comment: I've done this in another script, but how can I do from this one?

Comment: GameObject projectile = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, quaternion.identity)as GameObject;
 projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * 20f);